# ASP.Net 5 + Identity 3 Overriding default Roles implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

I have to extend default implementation of Roles in Identity 3. So I wrote subclasses:

```
public class ApplicationRole:IdentityRole
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}
public class ApplicationUserRole:IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then, since I want Entity Framework 7 to store my data in the same default tables I wrote the following in `OnModelCreating` method of `ApplicationDbContext`:

```
builder.Model.RemoveEntityType(new Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.EntityType(typeof(IdentityRole), builder.Model));
builder.Model.RemoveEntityType(new Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.EntityType(typeof(IdentityUserRole<string>),builder.Model));

builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");              
builder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { UserId = r.UserId, RoleId = r.RoleId });
builder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
```

Also I defined properties in `ApplicationDbContext`:

```
public DbSet<ApplicationUserRole> MyUserRoles { get; set; }
public DbSet<ApplicationRole> MyRoles { get; set; }
```

(I tried to override default `UserRoles` and `Roles` with `new`, but EF migration throw `AmbiguousMatchException`)
Now I suppose I have to register my custom implementation in app configuration, but I have no idea how. I whote in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(/*options*/)
```

and changed the superclass for `ApplicationDbContext`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser,ApplicationRole,string>
```

What else should I do? Or maybe I must address the task completely different?

Comment: Do you really need to do `RemoveEntityType` and add `MyUserRoles` and `MyUserRoles` to your context if you are already inheriting from `IdentityDbContext<...>`?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise EF's migration tool cannot bind my entities to the tables throwing "Cannot use table 'AspNetUserRoles' in schema '' for entity 'ApplicationUserRole' since it is being used for another entity."

Comment: Wait for a week, they're going to change all structures again, it will be Identity v.5 and will let you configure your authentication creating only 20 classes and overriding 80 methods... (ah, and don't forget interfaces, it has more than a thousand). And the best, this time it will be well documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source for [`IdentityDbContext`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityDbContext.cs) and it seems you cannot use your own `IdentityUserRole` class in Identity v3. In fact, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/585) to add this back in.

Comment: I've not had to extend those models in all of my projects, but I think it's a useful thing to have in for sure.